# Install banner on PWA disappears on scroll

Tags: html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, banner

Managed to convert my website to PWA, everything works fine but a small issue with Install Banner pop-up.

The banner appear on the bottom, as it should, but disappears when user scroll page down, then comes back if he is again up the top of the page.

is there any way to fix it or is it a feature of banner?

This is the website:
https://clicktoplay.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature of the banner. The [mini-info bar](https://web.dev/promote-install/#browser-promotion) will only be shown the first time a user visits the page, and won't be shown again for about 90 days.

If you'd like to add your own custom install experience, you can do that by listening for the [`beforeinstallprompt`](https://web.dev/customize-install/) event, and showing a button or other custom install promo.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will have a look.

Comment: just to clear some thing, do i need to implement listener for this event into my Service Workers?

Comment: No, listen for the event in your main app - https://web.dev/customize-install/ should walk you through the steps you need to follow.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir, that worked for me. I take it there is no such a thing for Ios users on safari is it?

Comment: Safari has Add to Home Screen, but it can only be initiated by the user and is buried in the share menu.